# Why does my emulator starts a DEFAULT activity before a LAUNCHER activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have this 2 activitys in my AndroidManifest.xml:

> [image]

I want the **Splash (LAUNCHER)** activity to be the first to load, but I don't understand why it's loading the **StartingPoint (DEFAULT)** activity.

This is what the console of Eclipse shows me:

[image]

If I remove the **Intent-filter** from **.StartingPoint** activity, the emulator stil loads the **StartingPoint** activity.

If I remove the entire **.StartingPoint** activity, the console shows me this :

[image]

This is my **manifest** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StartingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: remove intent filter from the starting point activity

Comment: I've tried like you said, and stil didn't

Comment: where is the starting point activity in your manifest its declaration should be inside the application tag

Comment: sorry, i've added the wrong code, this is the one i'm using

Comment: ya remove the intent filter from the starting point activity

Comment: share the code of the java files also then

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your StartingPoint Activity as follows,

```
<activity name=".StartingPoint"
          lable="YourLable" > 
</activity>
```

Just remove the  part from it and done.

Comment: nothing going to be wrong if he mention the intent filter for all the activities.

Comment: I've done that and stil no change... It seems that Eclipse want to start .StartingPoint activity :(

Answer (score 0):

please declare this is manifestfile..

```
  <activity
                android:name=".Splash"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

<activity name=".StartingPoint"
          lable="YourLable" > 
</activity>
```

whenever which activity is created in launcher activity then only this activity call .

Comment: you have to write first splash screen and then startingpoint ..
please put your manifest file here.

Comment: If I delete the intent-filter, no change

Comment: where is <activity name=".StartingPoint"
          lable="YourLable" > 
</activity> 

IN YOUR CODE?

Comment: plz chekc my another ans.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StartingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

use this one:

Comment: stil no change " Performing com.example.myfirstapp.StartingPoint activity launch" . . . I don't know, maybe i've done something wrong

Comment: please clean and build your app and check

Comment: Done, and nothing new. The same problem :(

Comment: remove  <activity
        android:name=".StartingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

check the run configurations of your AVD and see if you have set StartingPoint Activity there. that might be the only problem. else removing that default intent filter must help. there is no other thing missing. check the run config of your avd first.